# Get access to ActorService to get a list of all actors

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Trying to learn the basics of Azure Service Fabric. I have an app working where ive made a UserActorService and i can create and retrieve actors as well as saving state in them. But i cant figure out how i could get a list of all actors.

I have some understanding with this code:

```
     public async Task<List<string>> GetAllUserActors()
    {
        var fabricClient = new FabricClient();
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        ContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
        var result = new List<string>();

        do
        {
            var page = await actorService.GetActorsAsync(continuationToken, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            result.AddRange(page.Items.Select(i => i.ActorId.ToString()).ToList());
            continuationToken = page.ContinuationToken;

        } while (continuationToken != null);

        return result;
    }
```

The problem is i cant figure out where i should put this. The code needs access to the actual userActor services ActorService. And in the UserActorService i can only get a hold of it inside the UserActor.  I guess i could put inside UserActor and then call an individual UserActor to get this method return me a list.

But that shouldnt have to be the case as i think i shouldnt need to know the id of one UserActor to be able to see what actors there are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SF [Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-remoting) - from any application within the cluster - to fetch the data:

```
IActorService actorServiceProxy = ActorServiceProxy.Create(
    new Uri("fabric:/MyApp/MyService"), partitionKey);    
ContinuationToken continuationToken = null;
List<ActorInformation> activeActors = new List<ActorInformation>();

do
{
    PagedResult<ActorInformation> page = await actorServiceProxy.GetActorsAsync(continuationToken, cancellationToken);    
    activeActors.AddRange(page.Items.Where(x => x.IsActive));    
    continuationToken = page.ContinuationToken;
}
while (continuationToken != null);
```

Make sure to repeat the call for every Actor Service partition, by passing their respective `partitionKey`.

More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-enumerate).